# How can I back up my iphone if my touch screen is broken?

Tags: iphone

My touch screen capability on my 5c wasn't working, so I had to get a new phone. Before I close out my old phone, I have to back it up (hasn't been backed-up in a LONG time).... Is there any way to back-up my phone since the touch screen capability isn't working? (I'm on icloud, but it seems that wasn't backing up as it should have.) Thanks for your hep oh smart ones!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have made an backup to iCloud before and it's still turned on.

Backups made to iCloud run only automatically when the following criteria are met:

- Your device is connected to a power source.
- Your device is connected to a Wi-Fi network.
- Your device's screen is locked.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the iPhone to a Mac/PC with iTunes and back it up there. Any free and purchased apps can be dowloaded again. If you don't own a computer, see if you can borrow a friend's computer with iTunes. Make sure to make the backup **encrypted** so all your passwords & whatnot can be restored intact. Once you get the new iPhone, restore the backup. Once the new iPhone is working as you expect it, delete the backup from your friend's computer.

Comment: When you connect you iPhone to a new device, you have to accept the connection as trusted on the phone, which the OP can't do if the touch screen is completely broken. This solution would work only with a previously authorized computer.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying. This would be a GREAT solution if my touch screen worked.  Since it doesn't I can't allow access to itunes from my phone. I can use the voice feature, but it won't let me use that to accept itunes to back-up.  I think I may be out of luck.